# More accurate synonyms than "Mayan apocalypse"

Tags: phrase-requests

When describing [this announcement by Australia's Prime Minister](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebtj3gDaE64) on an language learning website, the best term I could come up with was "Mayan apocalypse". It felt a little inaccurate, as it's neither an apocalypse happening to Mayans, nor an apocalypse predicted by Mayans.

Wikipedia uses the term [2012 phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_phenomenon), which is a little vague, and one blog used the term "Mayan moment", which [confused](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53666/what-does-our-mayan-moment-mean-here) one person enough to ask a question about it.

Are there any more accurate synonyms for "Mayan apocalypse" that are still reasonably concise?

Comment: Since the Mayan apoclypse is entirely mythological, why not call it Kris Kringle?

Comment: One meaning of "apocalypse" in my dictionary is "something viewed as a prophetic revelation," and the end-of-the-world predictions incorrectly attributed to the Mayans fit that category.

Comment: Here is an off-the-cuff neologism since the presumed event relates to the end of the Mayan calendar's 5,125-year cycle:  **The Mayan Epochalypse**.

Comment: @Hellion  Or, in honor of the 50th anniversary of the Rolling Stones, the **14th Nervous B'ak'tun**.

Comment: @gmcgath wow - I never knew that!

Comment: Another portmanteau, if you want to emphasize its spurious nature: the *Mayan Apocryphalypse*.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm  The root meaning of *apocalypse* is *uncovering*; it's associated with the end of the world because of the enormous influence of the *Book of Revelation* which closes the Christian Bible on a vision of the end of history.

Comment: Actually, it's merely the **Mayan calendar roll-over** - their calendar is cyclic by nature, so it doesn't really end, it just returns to first day of first year of the new cycle. And are there even any predictions this is to be associated with anything happening? Because I don't think so, really. Just medial buzz.

Comment: I was going to write out a long explanatory answer giving the full linguistic exegesis of the multiple nuances of adjectives from proper nouns. But instead I'd rather spend my last moments eating cake.

Comment: But one last shot... the adjective doesn't have to mean literally the apocalypse of the Mayans (and no one else) or the apocalypse predicted by the Mayans (as ou pointed out, an apocalypse wasn't being predicted). It's just an apocalypse associated with Mayan culture. Anyway, the Mayans had their unpredicted slow moving apocalypse 900-1000AD. Despite this the Mayans are still there, just renamed as Mexicans or Guatemalans. So there's hope.

Comment: French fries aren't fried things that are French, nor things fried by the French, but I still call them French fries...

Comment: Should I flag to close as too localized?

Comment: Words that come to mind: "doomsday prophecy," "catastrophism." But I'm positive I've heard an excellent proper adjective relating to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us focus on the meaning or the etymological roots of *apocalypse*.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apocalypse:

> a·poc·a·lypse  (-pk-lps)
>       n.
>       1.
>       a. Apocalypse Abbr. Apoc. Bible The Book of Revelation.
>       b. Any of a number of anonymous Jewish or Christian texts from around the second century b.c. to the second century a.d. containing prophetic or symbolic visions, especially of the imminent destruction of the world and the salvation of the righteous.
>       2. Great or total devastation; doom: the apocalypse of nuclear war.
>       3. A prophetic disclosure; a revelation.
>
> [Middle English Apocalipse, from Late Latin Apocalypsis, from Greek apokalupsis, revelation, Apocalypse, from apokaluptein, to uncover : apo-, apo- + kaluptein, to cover; see kel-1 in Indo-European roots.]

Therefore, let us focus on the original meaning *revelation*, rather than the colloquially derived implication of *disaster*.

The Mayan calendar can be seen as a **revelation**, promulgating the end of a major era for the Mayans. Just like, if people expect to truly live a biblical life-style, then we would need to observe the 50 year sabbatical Jubilee. This 50 year sabbatical calendar is indeed apocalyptic as it reveals the change in life cycles necessary to regenerate a community. Or, consider even the I-Ching cycles which are also revelatory on changes of life-cycles.

However, for those of us who would not accept the revelatory roles of cultural or religious calendars, we could use either the term *myth* or *romance*, instead.

The meanings of the words *myth* and *romance* are often limited by the people who use them.

Myth can be used to describe an account that is true but which involves events that are extremely out of proportion that the likelihood of those events taking place together is highly improbable.

I recall someone asking why the title of a certain Chinese classic was translated as "Romance of the Three Kingdoms", as sex and affection were the least of concerns in the story.

Perhaps, you could use either of these phrases too:

- The romance of the Mayan Calendar
- The myth of the Mayan Calendar

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but quite a revelation!

Answer (score 1):

Around our house, we've been calling it the Mayan [Y2K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y2K), in reference to the parallels with the dreaded millennium bug that caused some concern leading up to the year 2000.

(Those parallels being: having to do with the calendar, and much ado about nothing.)

Comment: "... and much ado about nothing": Y2K was real. As for the Mayan date, it's a bit too early to tell for a few hours.  :)